Proof of Theorem 8.4.1, do carmo's Riemmanian Geometry
I have been reading through Theorem 8.4.1, which characterizes the universal covering spaces of constant sectional curvature manifolds:

Their proof:

However, I am having trouble understanding the last line in their proof, where they state that $f$ is a diffeomorphism "by Lemma 3.3 of Chap 7." However, I can't see why this statement should follow, as Lemma 3.3 discusses covering maps.

Is Do Carmo using Lemma 3.3 to show that f must be a covering map somehow? And, as a result, $\Delta$ is a covering space of the universal covering space, implying it must be the universal covering space itself?
Any insight would be deeply appreciated :)

Which part is unclear? A local isometry? Why a covering map is a diffeomorphism in this situation?

Your interpretation is correct. Since $f$ is an local isometry, it is a local diffeomorphism, hence by Lemma 3.3 it is a covering map. But then $\widetilde{M}$ is simply-connected, so $f$ must be bijective, and a bijective local isometry is a global isometry.
